# Specify all $\alpha, \beta$ homomorphisms which make this sequence half-exact!

Tags: homological-algebra, group-homomorphism, exact-sequence

Specify all $\alpha, \beta$ homomorphisms which make  this sequence half-exact!

$$0 \to \mathbb{Z}\xrightarrow{\alpha} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\beta} \mathbb{Z}_2 \to 0$$

From the definition, we must fulfil $Im(\alpha) < Ker(\beta)$. $\alpha=id, \beta=$ modulo $2$ is a good solution, since we have:

$$Im(\alpha)=\mathbb{Z} \subseteq Ker (\beta)=2\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z} $$

I have no idea if there are more solutions, or if not, how to prove that.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}\subset 2\mathbb{Z}$ ? Are you sure about that ?

Comment: Not really. Then the solution should be that there is no solution? :)

Comment: No, this is not what I am claiming. But seriously $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of all integers, this is not a subset of $2\mathbb{Z}$ which is the set of even numbers... Now can you find a map $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 2\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: Yeah, for every $x \in \mathbb{Z}, f(x)=2x$ should work.